# OpenCart resize function, white space is added

Tags: html, css, image, resize, opencart

I am currently working on a OpenCart project, and one of the pages requires a structure involving multiple images, being positioned closely together (see below). [image: Structure example]

All of the images that will be used are likely to be different sizes, but will need to be resized to a similar size (not the exact same size, but around the same). OpenCart's resize function is being used to resize these images, however the result leaves unwanted white space! (see below) [image: Desired outcome]

Is there any way to re-factor the code so the resized images have no white space around them?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="tbl">
   <div class="tbl-row">
      <div class="tbl-col">
         <div class="frame">
            <img class="imageFeatured" src="images/my-image.png" />
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post your markup. A question about css *really* needs markup to solve these sorts of issues.

Comment: Not used StackOverflow for long, thanks for the feedback. I've added my HTML markup. I've used a variation of CSS, but all has been unsuccessful so I currently have no CSS styling these elements.

Comment: there must be css acting on this somewhere? This question is very difficult to answer without it? although (possibly) could be solved using margin/padding:0 (but hard to advise)